Deploying with rehype-mathjax dependency on Vercel
I'm trying to deploy an app that's part of a large monorepo setup with turborepo. The app in question relies on another package that in turn has rehype-mathjax as a dependency. As far as I can tell, that is the only dependency that leads to canvas as a peer dependency.
If I run the build with node v20.*, I get an error that distutils does not exist because Vercel requires python 3.12 in their Node v20.* image.
If I run the the build node v18.19.1 with a pipfile setting the python version to 3.10, I get this error:
Error: /lib64/libz.so.1: version 'ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /vercel/path0/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libpng16.so.16)
This error however is preceded by a list of warnings, all similar to this:
../../node_modules/zlib-sync install: ../deps/zlib/inflate.c:1041:16: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
I've spent literally all day trying to get this to work, and I'm in a really tight spot with getting this app launched. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
